# Numpy Array reshape

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an Numpy array **immatrix** which is of immatrix.shape is (4535,)  and each element in the array immatrix is another array **imArray** of shape (12288,) . How can I reshape the array **immatrix**   to (4535,3,64,64)

```
    from PIL import Image
    import PIL.Image as Pim

    img_rows, img_cols = 64, 64
    # number of channels
    img_channels = 3

    ret = []
    for im2 in imlist_lettering:
        img = Image.open(dirPath_of_non_spam + '/' + im2);
        img = img.resize(( img_rows, img_cols), Pim.BILINEAR)
        imArray = array(img, dtype=float).flatten();
        if img_channels * img_cols *  img_rows == imArray.shape[0]:
            ret.append(imArray)

    immatrix = array(ret)
```

In here  the immatrix shape is (4535,)  and imArray shape is (12288) ,I want to reshape the immatix to (4535,3,64,64) .How to do that??

Comment: What is the `dtype` of `a`? I wonder why its shape isn't `(4535, 12288)`...

Comment: Can you clarify more your code? Where is a, is it imArray? What are Pim, cnn_model and Image? I supose they are modules from different  libraries you are importing, like PIL, but is only a guess. Please, put only the code relevant for the question

Comment: From deleted comments we've learned that your `imArray` varies in shape, so that `immatrix` is a 1d object array.  You can't reshape across the 'object' boundary.  You have to address the `imArray` shape issue first.